# Creating Arrays with automated names?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method in which I load tiles from a text file. The tiles are placed in an array when created, so that they can be cleared later. This has began to cause problems and I am wondering if there would be a way to create an array with a name that corresponds to the text file loaded. For example, I call

```
loadMap("map1");
```

With "map1" being the name of the txt file that the map is stored in. And if I were to call the loadMap method with the argument of "map1" how can I create an array titled something like "map1TileArray", or if the argument is "finalMap" I would want an array called "finalMapTileArray". Is it possible to do something like this, and if so, how?

**EDIT:**

I'm getting a NPE.

I declare my Map like this:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Tile>> tileMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Tile>>();
```

I then store an ArrayList in the tileMap with a string of the current map:

```
tileMap.put(map, tilearray);
```

But I get an error at this line:

```
if(tileMap.get(currentMap).size()>0) {
```

Which is the start of my unloadTiles method. currentMap is just the String for the map the program is on.

Comment: Your edit doesn't tell us enough to figure out what you could be doing wrong. You're putting nulls into the map, or your key is not one that was used to put in collections into the map, but you're not showing us why.

Answer (score 6):

You will want to use a Map such as a HashMap, perhaps a `Map<String, Integer[]>`. This will allow you to create an array of Integer (or whatever) and associate it with a String.

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Map<String, Integer[]> myMap = new HashMap<>();
      myMap.put("foo", new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
      myMap.put("bar", new Integer[] { 3, 4, 5 });
      myMap.put("spam", new Integer[] { 100, 200, 300 });

      for (String key : myMap.keySet()) {
         System.out.printf("%8s: %s%n", key, Arrays.toString(myMap.get(key)));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That was helpful and I though I got it working, but I'm getting a NPE. See my edit please.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and assign the value to a variable. Probably you will be better if use a List instead of an array

```
List<Integer> currentArray = loadMap("map1");

.... 
// inside
private List<Integer> loadMap( String fileName ) { 
    List<Integer> result = allTheMaps.get( fileName );
    if ( result == null ) { 
       // load it from file... 
       result = .... 
       allTheMaps.put( fileName, result ); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a map will work for this.

What others have not said is that you would probably also benefit from using a class to represent your tiles as well.

This way, any array logic you have for manipulating the tiles can be nicely encapsulated in one place. I would imagine something like this:

```
public class Tiles{
    private int[] tiles;
    private String name;
    private Tile(int[] tiles, String name){
        this.tiles = tiles;
    }

    public static Tiles getTiles(Map<String, Tiles> tilesCache, String tileName){
        if (tilesCache.containsKey(tileName)){
            return tilesCache.get(tileName);
        }
        // load from file
        return tile;
    }

    public void clear(Map<String, Tiles> tilesCache){
        tilesCache.remove(this.name);
        this.tiles = null;
    }

    //Other logic about tiles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) with a String as the key and an Integer[] for the value.

```
    Map<String, Integer[]> maps = new HashMap<String, Integer[]>();
```

and when you call your loadMap function you could do something like this.

```
    public Integer[] loadMap(String name) {
        if (maps.contains(name)) {
            return maps.get(name);
        }
        // Falls through if map is not loaded
        int[] mapData = new int[##];

        // load map

        maps.put(name, mapData);
        return mapData;
    }
```